# How to replace QRegExp in a string?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qregexp

I have a string. For example:

```
QString myString = "Today is Tuesday";
```

The requirement is: when user types a string, if that string is contained in `myString`, then that part in the `myString` should be bold, and case insensitive (`Qt::CaseInsensitive`), but the format of `myString` should remain (upper case characters should be upper case and lower case characters should be lower case).

For example:

- user types: `tu` -> Today is **Tu**esday
- user types: `ES` -> Today is Tu**es**day
- user types: `aY` -> Tod**ay** is Tuesd**ay**

This is my function:

```
void myClass::setBoldForMatching( const QString &p_text )
{
  QRegExp regExp( p_text, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp );
  if ( !p_text.isEmpty() )
  {       
    if ( myString.contains( regExp ) )
    {
      myString = myString.replace( p_text, QString( "<b>" + p_text + "</b>" ), Qt::CaseInsensitive );
    }
  }
}
```

This function is wrong because

user types `t` -> **t**oday is **t**uesday.

What I need is **T**oday is **T**uesday

How should I update my function?

Comment: u didn't describe full area of possible cases. What should happens if 
myString will be "Today is today" and user types "To"

Comment: Where is this text which supposed to be bold? Is it a `QTextEdit` or something else? Use of `QTextDocument` and `QTextCursor` can be more effective and simple than adding this html tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a different `QString::replace()`, which accepts a `QRexExp`, to substitute all occurrences.  The key to this is that we need a *capture group* in order to replace the original text in the substitution, using a back-reference (`\1`):

```
#include <QRegExp>

QString setBoldForMatching(QString haystack, const QString& needle)
{
    if (needle.isEmpty()) return haystack;
    const QRegExp re{"("+QRegExp::escape(needle)+")", Qt::CaseInsensitive};
    return haystack.replace(re, "<b>\\1</b>");
}
```

### Demo

```
#include <QDebug>
int main()
{
    qInfo() << setBoldForMatching("THIS DAY (today) is Tuesday.", "Day");
}
```

> THIS **DAY** (to**day**) is Tues**day**.

Comment: wow, your solution made me read back-reference. That is new to me. thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question about this. What should I translate your answer, if I use QRegularExpression?

Comment: That's probably worth creating a new question for (if you can't find an existing one).

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Change your `setBoldForMatching` like this:

```
void myClass::setBoldForMatching(const QString &p_text)
{
    QRegExp regExp(p_text, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::RegExp);
    QString str = myString;
    
    if (p_text.isEmpty()) {
        label->setText(myString);
        return;
    }
    
    int count = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    QStringList matches;
    
    while ((pos = regExp.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
        ++count;
        pos += regExp.matchedLength();
        matches.append(regExp.capturedTexts());
    }
    
    foreach (const QString &match, matches) {
        str.replace(match, "<b>" + match + "</b>");
    }
}
```

I have decided to keep the original content of `myString`, so the result is contained in `str` instead.

## Example

I have prepared a small example for you in order to demonstrate the result. The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-BoldMatch).

## Result

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: as i wrote, the question didn't describe full set of posiible cases. I think u should fully understand what is needed before post any answers

Comment: @borune, yes, I have seen that.

Comment: Why `p_text.toLower()` rather than just `p_text`?  I don't see that the conversion has any benefit.  Also, problem statement suggests we want `QRegExp::FixedString` rather than `QRegExp::RegExp`.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing a match with `p_text` will always change the case to the one of `p_text`. So you have to do the replacement step by step, like this:

```
void myClass::setBoldForMatching(const QString &p_text) {
    QRegExp regExp( p_text, Qt::CaseInsensitive, QRegExp::FixedString );

    QString start = "<b>";
    QString stop = "</b>";

    int i=-1;
    while (-1 != (i=myString.indexOf(regExp,i+1))) {
        myString.insert(i, start);
        i += start.size();
        i += p_text.size();
        myString.insert(i, stop);
        i += stop.size();
    }
}
```

As you can see, with this code, the start and stop tags will be inserted before and after the match, without changing the matched sub-string itself.

Here are some test cases:

- Today is Tuesday + `tu` --> Today is **Tu**esday
- Today is Tuesday + `ES` --> Today is Tu**es**day
- Today is Tuesday + `aY` --> Tod**ay** is Tuesd**ay**
- Today is Tuesday + `t` --> **T**oday is **T**uesday
- Today is today + `To` --> **To**day is **to**day