# Case insensitive search mode with QRegularExpression

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp, qregularexpression

This question is an expanded question of this :
[How to replace QRegExp in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054261/how-to-replace-qregexp-in-a-string/52056165?noredirect=1#comment91581630_52056165)

In that question, problem is solved. But now I need to use QRegularExpression instead of QRegExp. How should I transfer the answer of Toby Speight?

Comment: What have you tried?  In particular, what makes you think that simply replacing `QRegExp` with `QRegularExpression` won't work in this case (with the proviso you change `Qt::CaseInsensitive` to `QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption`)?

Comment: @G.M.: thanks for your answer, Actually that is what i am looking for. I dont know how to replace `Qt::CaseInsensitive` in `QRegularExpression`. :)

Comment: But G.M. said exactly what to replace it with: `QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption`, it's of type `QRegularExpression::PatternOption`.

Comment: @KubaOber: yeah, his answer solved my problem already.

Comment: Please consider finalizing the question if the answer below works for you.

Answer (score 2):

[`QRegExp`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) case insensitive search mode is enabled with [`Qt::CaseInsensitive`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt.html#CaseSensitivity-enum).

When you use [`QRegularExpression`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) that is based on PCRE regex engine, you may use [`QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#PatternOption-enum):

> The pattern should match against the subject string in a case insensitive way. This option corresponds to the `/i` modifier in Perl regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In python, it's:

```
re = QRegularExpression(pattern, QRegularExpression.CaseInsensitiveOption | QRegularExpression.DotMatchesEverythingOption)
```

And if you need 2 options

```
re = QRegularExpression(pattern, QRegularExpression.CaseInsensitiveOption | QRegularExpression.DotMatchesEverythingOption)
```